# Django cannot login user after registration

Tags: django, authentication, django-users

The app has a basic registration form. I am trying to authenticate users after they fill it out. However, I'm unable to authenticate them. Am I going about this in the correct way?

Here is the view:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             user = request.user
             password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
             #this works
             try:
                 validate_password(password1, user)
             except ValidationError as e:
                   form.add_error('password1', e)  
                   return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form}) 
             profile = form.save(commit=False)
             profile.save() 
             user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
             # this login not working, user is never authenticated
             login(request, user)
             return redirect('agree')             
        else:
             raise ValidationError("Form is not valid. Try Again.")
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form}).
```

Here is the forms.py. The model here is just the Django base user model.

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =  ['username']

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password2


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

User never gets registered and authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

For `authenticate()` method, you need to pass `request`(reference [**`authenticate()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L40) method in django backend). For example:

```
authenticate(request, username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
```

Also why do you need authenticate method as you already have the user object:

```
profile = form.save()  # <-- Its an user instance, name of the variable should be user
login(request, profile, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
return redirect('agree')
```

Finally, you implementation looks bit fishy, why are you using `user=request.user`, is the user already logged in? I think this part of code is unnecessary:

```
user = request.user
password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
try:
    validate_password(password1, user)
except ValidationError as e:
    form.add_error('password1', e)  
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry new to Django. Don't really understand what I'm doing.

Comment: It did not work. I removed authenticate and I get this error: "You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user."